# How to define routing for simple subfolder/action case?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to make simple ASP.NET MVC application (or call it hhtp service) so i can post some simple data using POST method.
I want to use the following url:

www.mysite.com/api/postdata

Yet I havenit figured out how to configure RouteConfig and contoller.
My best attempt was, and I have tried dozens others is:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ApiPostData",
        url: "api/postdata",
        defaults: new { controller = "Api", action = "PostData" }
    );
}
```

My controller:

```
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    //[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostData(PostData postData)
    {
        // save to database
        retun Json(true);
    }
}
```

Type PostData is also declared as a simpler object.

Why does this not work? I always get the error 404. I have tried many many variations around that. Read hundreds of pages, yet not single working example.
A have also came  across something called areas but I refuse to believe that so much coding and complications are necessary for such a trivial task. This cannot be true.

EDIT - UPDATE:

I have prepared even more trivial test case:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // this executes, checked it in debugger
    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Test",
            url: "api/test",
            defaults: new { controller = "Api", action = "Test" }
    );
}


public class ApiController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return Content("TEST TEST TEST");
    }
}
```

So, if i call it with

```
localhost/site/api/test
```

I should get "TEST TEST TEST" as response. Wrong !!!
What I get is

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/site/api/test'.No type was found that matches the controller named 'test'.

What is going on ????

UPDATE

I have in desperation tried this direct version with no "folder".

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Test2",
            url: "test",
            defaults: new { controller = "Api", action = "Test" }
    );
}
```

and this I can call with

```
www.mysite.com/test
```

and it returns TEST TEST TEST as it should.

UPDATE

It seems it is a bug.
If I reconfigure the above MapRoute to target

www.mysite.com/xxx/test

it works. It seems that if url contains string "api" it breaks.

Comment: This must work even with the default MVC route. Show the code of PostData class and the request you make.

Comment: PostData does not matter. It just get filled with POST request data. But we do not even come to that point. And the request in shown above.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem when I test using IIS Express. As far as I can see your route definition works fine with ASP.NET MVC where I can both GET and POST to `api/test` and get a 200 OK with the text string. Looking at your examples your sample URL's are very inconsistent: `www.mysite.com/api/postdata`, `localhost/site/api/test`, `www.mysite.com/test`. I suggest that you test your routes once more and make sure that you haven't made any silly mistakes. There are certainly no bugs or limitations in ASP.NET MVC that makes it impossible to create the route you want.

Comment: There are no inconsistencies. And there is a bug. MVC 4 tooling configures the project wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ApiPostDAta",
    url: "api/{action}/{PostData}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Api", action = "PostData", PostData = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This will match the request like "www.mySite.com/Api/PostData/12345" for example.

Comment: I want it to match www.mysite.com/api/postdata exactly. Lowercase letters, nothing appended after post data. and, do you know for sure or are you just guessing?

Comment: It is not a guess I created new empty MVC project and just added the route before a default one. After that created ApiController class and a method public JsonResult PostData(PostData postData). Fake class PostData with only property int Data { get; set; }. This works for sure!